# How to support Zoom like Safari with WKWebView on macOS

Tags: macos, wkwebview

In Safari the user can enlarge the content by using the Zoom commands, like Command +. This enlarges not only the content, including font size, but it also adjusts the content to remain between the window margins.

I want to achieve the same feature with WKWebView on macOS, but I don't know how to do that when using the `loadRequest()` command on the web view control.

I have tried the following, without much success:

- Inject javascript like `"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust='150%'"`. It seems that `webkitTextSizeAdjust` is not supported anymore on the macOS version of WKWebView, see https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/145168/webkit.
- Use the `magnification` property. This works, but this simply enlarges (or minimises) everything, without adjusting the content to remain between the control width (viewport), like Safari does.

Please take note that I'm using `loadRequest()`, not `loadHTMLString()`.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same prblem, and found a solution. You need to set an JavaScript code injection to the `WkWebView` configuration. The scale number needs to be set in the JavaScript code.

The full code is shown below:

```
NSString *jScript = @"document.body.style.zoom = 0.8";
WKUserScript *wkUScript = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:jScript injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:YES];

WKUserContentController *wkUController = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
[wkUController addUserScript:wkUScript];

WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
configuration.userContentController = wkUController;

WKWebView *webContentView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0,sizeWidth, sizeHeight) configuration:configuration];
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to injecting javascript, as described in the accepted answer of @elsonpeng, you can also adjust the zoom level at any time like this (Swift):

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.style.zoom = 1.5", completionHandler: nil)
```

This can of course also be used in combination with `WKNavigationDelegate`, to execute the script when the page is fully loaded:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.style.zoom = 1.5", completionHandler: nil)
}
```

This approach is a bit more flexible, but a bit slower then code injection, depending on the complexity of the page that you load.